# fill each row of a dataframe with zero starting from the column in which the values decreases with respect to the value in the previous column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, fill

I would like to fill each row of a dataframe with zero starting from the column in which the value decreases with respect to the value in the previous column

I have the following Dataframe:

```
ActualDf = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0], [2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0], [3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]),
columns=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

)

And I would like to obtain this one

```
DesiredDf = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]),
columns=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])
```

How is it possible to da that in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `diff` and `lt` to find where the difference is negative, and then use `cumsum` and `gt` to flag all cells after the first negative value.

```
ActualDf[ActualDf.diff(axis=1).lt(0).cumsum(1).gt(0)] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach similar using a `mask`:

```
DesiredDf =ActualDf.mask(ActualDf.diff(axis=1).lt(0).cummax(axis=1), 0)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
1  1  1  1  2  2  3  0  0  0  0   0
2  2  2  2  3  3  5  0  0  0  0   0
3  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
4  3  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
5  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```